# Desktop managment software for Flickr (Linux)

Tags: linux, file-management, photography

I'm using [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/) as a web based storage for some of my photography. Flickr offers 1 TB space for free, offers pretty good sharing features, good management through collections and sets, but their uploading and downloading photography options aren't the best ones around. I'm  primarily searching for software to download from Flickr, able to manage tags, comment, sets and collections from desktop. I'm running on Ubuntu and  most of existing desktop photo managers offers option to only upload to Flickr.

**Must features:**

- Upload to Flickr with ability to add folders and photography recursively
- Downloading from Flickr (without alternating photography
  metadata)
- Managing Flickr Collections and/or Sets
- Managing Photo metadata
- Linux (Ubuntu) native software

**Nice to have but not a must**

- Export/upload to google+ (picasa web albums), Box.com or trovebox
- Ability to recognize duplicates
- Logging with possibility to export to CSV (upload and  download history)

Not really interested in software to run in Wine, but may consider if needed.